# How to drag a bitmap with page curl effect in android?

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, page-curl

I am using [android page curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) in my project. Each bitmap is working fine with page curl effect. But I need to have drag functionality also. I want that when a user long click on a bitmap the page curl animation will be off and that bitmap start dragging with user's finger.

Can any one suggest me with a piece of code, how can I achieve above functionality?

Comment: Check this code here please, might be useful: https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

Comment: I am using that library. I want suggestion to make changes according to my requirement.